# mongo default config

Tags: windows, mongodb

I have Windows 8 developer computer and mongodb for win32.
Mongo uses `\data\db` dbpath for data by default.

I may set `dbpath` in config file, but I have to add `-f \path\to\config` to `mongo` or `mongod` commands.

How can I set default config file for `mongo` and `mongod`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no default location for a configuration file. Not on linux either. The packaged installers create a startup script that starts the daemon with the `-f` option.

You could create a service under windows that does just that for you, or run the daemon from a .bat-file.

Answer (score 3):

Why did not want to use:

```
mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf
mongod -f /etc/mongodb.conf
```

You could write a `bat` file with this parametrs.

Comment: I already wrote a bat file for it, but I think that this method is dirty.

Comment: @DmitryR it's not dirty. also it's possible to create windows service with needed startup params.